# Progress Event not Triggering ONLINE

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a Flash Photogallery and I have a problem with my preloader. My gallery works fine offline(in simulating download) but the problem is when it's online the loading percentage won't show up. So far I figured out that the ProgressEvent is not triggering when gallery loads full size image. Sometimes it triggers on 100%, sometimes it triggers on time but usually it don't trigger. Here is the link of my gallery and some code: solarratko.netii.net

```
public function kreni(f:String) //function that start when user click on thumbnail
    {
        URLrequest=new URLRequest(f); //URLrequest for image in full size
        dspLoader.load(URLrequest); //loading the image

        preloader.visible = true;//prelaoder that shows up is visible
        h.visible=true;//text area for percentage is visible
        dspLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progres);//adding progress event
        dspLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, kraj);//adding complete event

    }
    public function progres(e:Event):void
    {
        var perc:Number = e.target.bytesLoaded / e.target.bytesTotal;//calculatin percentage
        h.text = Math.ceil(perc*100).toString();//displaying percentage wich is not working online or it start too late

    }
    public function kraj(e:Event):void
    {
        h.text="";
        preloader.visible = false;
        h.visible=false;
    }
```

Comment: Does the image load immediately? If so, it could have been cached by the browser and therefore doesn't have to be downloaded.

Comment: No, image loads normally and the preloader shows up and the text with percenatge shows up but the progressevent is not triggering(I know that because the text is visible but it is not showing the value of percentage)

Comment: Try moving the `dspLoader.load(URLrequest);` line _below_ the lines where you are adding the event listeners.

Comment: Pretty sure it crashes before it gets to load anything.